# Error when reading 'migrate': No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, dart, migration

I want to use migration tool as described [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#migration-tool).

But I get `Error: Error when reading 'migrate': No such file or directory`

Here my dart version and error

```
xxx@xxx-:~/Desktop/xxx$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 2.4.0 (Unknown timestamp) on "linux_x64"
xxx@xxx-I:~/Desktop/xxx$ dart migrate

Error: Error when reading 'migrate': No such file or directory
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Your version of dart is old. Upgrade it.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore how to upgrade ? 
`My flutter version Flutter 2.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c5a4b4029c (3 days ago) • 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
Engine • revision 40441def69
Tools • Dart 2.12.0`

Comment: You need to upgrade *dart*, not flutter. You may have installed dart separately in the past. As you can see from your own logs, the version of dart from flutter is 2.12.0, while just dart is 2.4.0.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore how to upgrade? I saw only upgrade sdk, but not dart upgrade.

Comment: Remove the old version of dart from your system.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore can I know how ?  O.o?

Comment: Find where you downloaded it, delete it.

Answer (score 3):

**

### First solution :**

```
dart --version
```

If the dart sdk version is less than 2.12.0

Then try:

```
Flutter upgrade --force
```

or

```
   dart upgrade
```

If dart migrate still doesn'tt work then jump to the second solution

### **Second solution :**

since dart is already downloaded as part of flutter
Make sure first that it hasn't been downloaded twice

on Mac try :

```
where dart
```

on MS windows , check your path in the environment variables.

If there was more than one path for the dart sdk , then this is problem

In my case I had it installed twice

```
/usr/local/bin/dart
/Users/USER/Documents/flutter/bin/dart
```

so I removed the first one by  (mac os)

```
rm /usr/local/bin/dart
```

The moment I did that the issue was fixed.

Try

```
dart --version
```

again and you should be having the latest version of dart that comes with flutter and you should be able to run succsfully

```
dart migrate
```